# Best way to transfer data on BlackBerry

Tags: java, blackberry

I am making a voice note recording application and it should send voice notes from the BlackBerry to a server.  What the best approach for doing the data transfer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For large data transfers it is best to use HTTP (i.e. HTTP POST the data to a server) using the following transports:

- Wi-Fi (if available)
- Direct TCP (need to specify APN on many GSM devices)
- WAP2 (not all carriers support this)

You could try to send data over BIS/BES but there are usually limits to the size of transfers over those transports - plus you need to be an Alliance Member with RIM in order to use BIS.

Comment: Thank you very much, by any chance can you lead me to an example on HTTP on the blackberry?

Comment: This would be a good start: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Connecting-your-BlackBerry-http-and-socket-connections-to-the/td-p/206242